# MariaDB regex with Concat only catches some results

Tags: regex, mariadb, concatenation

I have a table of VARCHAR column and I need to check it for a value:

Typical data values are:

```
Brize Norton (501, 622, 2624, 4624, 4626)
Wyton (7006, 7010, 7630)
Waddington (2503, 7006)
Honington (2623)
Marham (2620, 7010)
Leeming (607 & 609)
```

The only part I need to check is that it contains the full number only. I can not check *just* the number because `LIKE '%607%'` will also incorrectly match `6070` or `2607`, so I check the number and a variation of wrappers as so:

I have this query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM aux WHERE aux.name REGEXP CONCAT('[(,\h]',:num, '[),\h]')
```

this is intended to catch any (`( or, or <whitespace>`, `a variable number value` , `) or , or <whitespace>` ) in a VARCHAR column.

This works on some numbers but not on others;

An example :

```
:num = 2620
SELECT id, name FROM aux WHERE aux.name REGEXP CONCAT('[(,\h]',:num, '[),\h]')
```

Result:

> "Marham (2620, 7010)"

but fails on other numbers:

```
 :num = 7010
SELECT id, name FROM aux WHERE aux.name REGEXP CONCAT('[(,\h]',:num, '[),\h]')
```

Result:

> (Nothing)

How can I tell the REGEXP to catch the data shaped as above `( or, or <whitespace>`, `a variable number value` , `) or , or <whitespace>`.

I have tried `EXPLAIN` on my query but that doesn't help me at see the REGEXP mechanism.

I have replaced `\h` with `\s` but this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `CONCAT('(?:\D|^)',:num, '(?:\D|$)')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew after writing this question I have just now tried that and this does work, but I am now curious why the above doesn't return correct results?

Comment: Interesting. Documentation doesn't mention \D among supported [character classes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regular-expressions-overview/#character-classes).

Comment: There is nothing from the PCRE regex point of view that could prevent from matching. Then, did you try `\\h` or `\\s` instead of `\h` and `\s`? Also, are you sure the suggestion works? Maybe your MariaDB is not PCRE-powered, then you need `CONCAT('([^0-9]|^)',:num, '([^0-9]|$)')`

Comment: @raina77ow my IDE suggested `\D` but was previously using `\d` with the same results

Comment: Ah, I see now. The PCRE support has been added in MariaDB 10.5; before that, only POSIX 1003.2 compatible character classes (`[:alpha:], [:digit:]` etc.) were avaiable. But yes, both \D and \s were added, so it's really weird one works but not the other. Which version of Maria is used?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I have checked double slashing and that voided all results. I have found that the issue is `\s` and `\h` not being recognised. I use a standard space character and the REGEX works fine.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, checking MariaDB it is only version 5.5.68 so that explains everything! Thanks

Comment: @raina77ow actually could you put your comment as an answer and that will solve this. It's a dumb issue, simply the server MariaDB is old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, it's a matter of versions, as [until version 10.0.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1005-release-notes/) MariaDB used the POSIX 1003.2 compliant regular expression library. This library didn't support `\h`, `\d` etc. character classes, using their POSIX variants - `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]` and so on.

In your case, however, it seems you might just replace `\s` or `\h` with a single whitespace in that character class:

```
REGEXP CONCAT('[(, ]', :num, '[), ]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MariabDB does not support PCRE regex syntax, so only POSIX-compliant regex can be used. Neither `\h` nor `\s` are POSIX compliant, in POSIX world, `\h` is "equivalent" to `[:blank:]` and `\s` to `[:space:]`.

**More POSIX/PCRE character class equivalent patterns**:

| POSIX Character Class | PCRE | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[:alnum:]` | `[:alnum:]` / `[\p{L}\p{N}]` | Alphanumeric |
| `[:alpha:]` | `\p{L}` | Alphabetic |
| `[:blank:]` | `\h` | Whitespace |
| `[:cntrl:]` | `[:cntrl:]` / `\p{Cc}` / `\p{C}` | Control characters |
| `[:digit:]` | `\d` | Digits |
| `[:graph:]` | `[:graph:]` | Graphic characters |
| `[:lower:]` | `\p{Ll}` | Lowercase alphabetic |
| `[:print:]` | `[:print:]` | Graphic or space characters |
| `[:punct:]` | `[\p{P}\p{S}]` | Punctuation |
| `[:space:]` | `\s` | Space, tab, newline, and carriage return |
| `[:upper:]` | `\p{Lu}` | Uppercase alphabetic |
| `[:xdigit:]` | `[:xdigit:]` / `[A-Fa-f0-9]` | Hexadecimal digit |

You can use

```sql
REGEXP CONCAT('[(,[:blank:]]', :num, '[),[:blank:]]')
REGEXP CONCAT('[(,[:space:]]', :num, '[),[:space:]]')
```

If you simply want to enforce *numeric boundaries* use

```sql
CONCAT('([^0-9]|^)',:num, '([^0-9]|$)')
CONCAT('([^[:digit:]]|^)',:num, '([^[:digit:]]|$)')
```

The regex details:

- `[(,[:space:]]` - a `(`, `,` or any whitespace char
- `[),[:space:]]` - a `)`, `,` or any whitespace char
- `[(,[:blank:]]` - a `(`, `,` or a horizontal whitespace char
- `[),[:blank:]]` - a `)`, `,` or a horizontal whitespace char
- `([^0-9]|^)` / `([^[:digit:]]|^)` - any non-digit char or start of string
- `([^0-9]|$)` / `([^[:digit:]]|$)` - any non-digit char or end of string.